# Split text file aftering finding a match

Tags: php, parsing

I am trying to search for a string match then split the file contents. After some trial and error, I am hoping someone can provide a helping hand. After fgetcsv, searching a string becomes almost pointless. Ideally, I would like to find each occurrence of "appointment", and split the contents with a comma.

```
if (($handle = fopen('file.csv', "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    if(preg_match('/appointments/', $data, $matches, 0))
    {
        $split = preg_split("/,/", $data);
        print_r($split);

    }
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

The print statements gives back nothing.

Comment: `$data` is going to be an array, not a string. So you would need to loop over each element of the array, or access the element you need only and then use that.

Answer (score 0):

What do you meant by splitting the content with a comma? Or do you want to add a comma after each "appointments"?

Instead of `fgetcsv`, use `fread` and replace "appointments" with "appointments, " using `str_replace`

```
$filename = 'file.csv';
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

$contents = str_replace('appointments', 'appointments, ', $contents);
echo $contents;
```

Comment: The file is comma delimited, and I need to search "appointment" field, and get the columns after. After using preg_split on "appointment:" and a foreach, I viewed source, and turns out the file has special charsets.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, the file has ASCII characters which need cleaning before processing.

After getting the file and looping, strip the contents of ASCII character sets.

```
$stripAscii = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','',$data);
$datePos = strpos($stripAscii,'Appointment:');
$data = substr($data, $datePos); 
$data = str_replace('Appointment:', ' ', $row2);
```

Now, all fields after "Appointment:" is returned.